# How are cookies passed in the HTTP protocol?

Tags: http, cookies

How are cookies passed in the HTTP protocol?

Comment: Best overview I've read this is this one by Zakas:  http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/05/05/http-cookies-explained/

Answer (score 357, accepted):

The server sends the following in its response header to set a cookie field.

`Set-Cookie:`*name*`=`*value*

If there is a cookie set, then the browser sends the following in its request header.

`Cookie:`*name*`=`*value*

See the [HTTP Cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) article at Wikipedia for more information.

Comment: Is it true that the cookie only work with GET/POST verb, but not CONNECT?

Comment: @PerlDev There is nothing that I can see in [rfc2109](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2109) that says that it should not work with requests other than GET/POST, but I suspect that the browser and server implementations may not implement it in those cases.

Comment: Note that according to [RFC 2109](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt) if a user agent or browser sends multiple cookies, it will put them in a single field delimited by semicolons: `Cookie: name1=value1; name2=value2; ...`

Comment: but where are the cookies stored, client side? In `localStorage`?

Answer (score 44):

Cookies are passed as HTTP headers, both in the request (client -> server), and in the response (server -> client).

Comment: so in any request that is made, are all the cookies ipso facto sent?

Answer (score 38):

Apart from what it's written in other answers, other details related to path of cookie, maximum age of cookie, whether it's secured or not also passed in Set-Cookie response header. For instance:

`Set-Cookie:`*name*`=`*value*[`; expires=`*date*][`; domain=`*domain*][`; path=`*path*][`; secure`]

---

However, not all of these details are passed back to the server by the client when making next HTTP request.

You can also set `HttpOnly` flag at the end of your cookie, to indicate that your cookie is httponly and must not allowed to be accessed, in scripts by javascript code. This helps to prevent attacks such as session-hijacking.

For more information, see [RFC 2109](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt). Also have a look at 
Nicholas C. Zakas's article, [*HTTP cookies explained*](https://web.archive.org/web/20170122122852/https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/05/05/http-cookies-explained/).

Comment: Here is a direct link to Zakas's article, rather than a wayback link: https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2009/05/05/http-cookies-explained/

Answer (score 14):

create example script as resp :

```
#!/bin/bash

http_code=200
mime=text/html

echo -e "HTTP/1.1 $http_code OK\r"
echo "Content-type: $mime"
echo "Set-Cookie: name=F"
echo
```

then make executable and execute like this.

```
./resp | nc -l 12346
```

open browser and browse URL: http://localhost:12346
you will see Cookie value which is sent by Browser

```
    [aaa@bbbbbbbb ]$ ./resp | nc -l -p 12346
    GET / HTTP/1.1
    Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:12346
    Connection: keep-alive
    Cache-Control: max-age=0
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6
    Cookie: name=F
```

Comment: What if there are multiple cookies? Are they separated by comma's?

Comment: think they are set as a new cookie.

Cookie: name=F
Cookie:name=A

Comment: @MarkBuikema, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wininet/http-cookies . They are sent like: Cookie: <name>=<value> [;<name>=<value>]...