# HTTP Status 401 - Full authentication is required to access this resource

Tags: spring, rest, http

On some link I authorized with basic type: username,password and get session: "25C87AA2BFBFB3A1B70FECD9F4441738".
Now I want manually get access to other resource with same session and put header:
    Cookie: JSESSIONID=25C87AA2BFBFB3A1B70FECD9F4441738

But error appears:
    HTTP Status 401 - Full authentication is required to access this resource

Comment: What do you mean by manually get access?

Comment: mean, if i already have session_id, a don't need authorize again.

Comment: browser set session id to cookie, and sent back every request... I have no browser but mobile device. My question is, how to send manually http request, so this message not appear.

Comment: Are you using spring rest template?

Comment: no, just spring security

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add a HTTP header named `Cookie` and the value should be the `JSESSIONID=<JSESSIONID VALUE>`, As per you question the value should be `JSESSIONID=25C87AA2BFBFB3A1B70FECD9F4441738`

By this the server will check that the session already authenticated if authenticated it will allow to access the resource.

<del>**Update 1**</del>

<del>According to [Postman Docs](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests) there are some headers are restricted, unfortunately `Cookie` is one of them.</del>

**Update 2**

As per the [Postman Docs](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests) from version v0.9.6 sending restricted headers are possible by using Inspector extension.

Refrences

1. [How are cookies passed in the HTTP protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467114/how-are-cookies-passed-in-the-http-protocol)
2. [Under what conditions is a JSESSIONID created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595872/under-what-conditions-is-a-jsessionid-created)

Comment: What technology you are using in the client side?

Comment: I try to send request with programm Postman https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam - Hi Karthik, can you please help me on this . I really need help urgently as I am stuck with this since past 4 days. Thanks in advance!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53090739/spring-boot-jwt-security-full-authentication-is-required

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have spring security related maven dependency in your pom.xml. Remove the  dependency from pom.xml if not used. The issue will be resolved.