# httpservletrequest getCookies() or getHeader()

Tags: java, servlets

I want to accept data from a client.
What are the pros and cons of each approach?

```
HttpServletRequest request = retriveRequest();
Cookie [] cookies = request.getCookies();
for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
     if ("my-cookie-name".equals(cookie.getName())) {
          String value = cookie.getValue();
         //do something with the cookie's value.
     }
}
```

or

```
String request.getHeader("header-name");
```

As I read [How are cookies passed in the HTTP protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467114/how-are-cookies-passed-in-the-http-protocol)

> Cookies are passed as HTTP headers, both in the request (client -> server), and in the response (server -> client).

Comment: request.getCookies() may return you null if no cookie is set, so make sure you check 'cookies' array is not null before 'for' loop.

Comment: Any reason you've discounted request parameters?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[getCookies](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getCookies()), frees you from parsing the Cookie header string, and creating a java object out of it.  Otherwise you will have to do something like:

```
String rawCookie = request.getHeader("Cookie");
String[] rawCookieParams = rawCookie.split(";");
for(String rawCookieNameAndValue :rawCookieParams)
{
  String[] rawCookieNameAndValuePair = rawCookieNameAndValue.split("=");
}
// so on and so forth.
```

Comment: I agree with you, thanks. 

How about this case?
What if I want just to pass data. Either I pass it via cookie or just header, does not matter. 

   for example

String str = request.getHeader("my-param");

And I do not need to parse this string because it will be value I need.

Comment: And one more thing, cookies are useful to store data from a site and send this data after some time. If I exchange with the server without cookies, where do I store say "locale-param", "preferred theme" of stuff like this?

Comment: Locale should go to Accept-Language field e.g en/ja etc... For custom headers you can define your own custom headers as well.

Comment: How to create a `request` object of `HttpServletRequest` ?

Comment: @Kavipriya request is just a variable name for HttpServletRequest. Its the same