# How can I manually set custom cookie and header values using Volley in Android?

Tags: java, android, cookies, header, android-volley

I'm getting started working with Android Studio, and I'd like to make a simple application to grab raw HTML from a URL. I've set up Volley to do this using the basic example at http://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html, which works fine for public URLs.

The URL I want to access requires specific headers and cookies, which I have the static values of on hand. How can I assign these values to my request?

```
public void grabHTML(View view) {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = getString(R.string.urlpath);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                   mTextView.setText(response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            mTextView.setText(error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

EDIT:

I was able to apply the solution from [How are cookies passed in the HTTP protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467114/how-are-cookies-passed-in-the-http-protocol) to manually set my request headers.

Answer (score 1):

Use the solution [How are cookies passed in the HTTP protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467114/how-are-cookies-passed-in-the-http-protocol) here to manually set headers to your request. My code ended up looking like this:

```
package com.pesonal.webrequestexample;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

    public class StringRequestWithCookies extends StringRequest {
    private Map<String, String> cookies;

    public StringRequestWithCookies(String url, Map<String, String> cookies, Response.Listener<String> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Request.Method.GET, url, listener, errorListener);
        this.cookies = cookies;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("header1","value");
        headers.put("header2","value");

        return headers;
    }
}
```

and in the relevant activity...

```
public void grabHTML(View view) {
        String url = getString(R.string.urlpath);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequestWithCookies stringRequest = new StringRequestWithCookies(
            url,getCookies(),
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        mTextView.setText(response);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                mTextView.setText(error.getMessage());
            }
        });
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```