# Java Apache HTTP Client - Save Cookie for next request

Tags: java, cookies, web-crawler

i'm starting with Programming Java and wan't to create a simple "Backend Crawler". For this i need a login function by Post thats not problem but how i can do the cookies wars saved and on the next request the Script don't need login again?

Can you give me a example? I can't find a solution in the internet.

Maybe you can explain me how i can do the next request with the Cookies from the first Page? :)

Hope for your answer.

Sorry for my bad english.

Here is my first Logintest :P

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class Login {

    public static String loginAndGetHTML() throws Exception {
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        String html;

        HttpPost HttpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.google.com");
        List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "admin"));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "1234"));
        HttpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
        HttpPost.addHeader("Referer", "http://tutorials.amazingcode.de/login/index.php");
        HttpPost.addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0");
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(HttpPost);

        try {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            html = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
        } finally {
            response.close();
        }

        if(html.contains("Falsche Nutzerdaten")) {
            throw new Exception("Login fehlgeschlagen");
        }



        return html;
    }

    public static String parseHTML(String html) throws Exception {
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        String zahl = doc.getElementById("zahl").text();
        return zahl;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to retrieve the Set-Cookie header from the response, store its value,
and ask following requests with Cookie header and that value.

see this post for more explainer on cookies [How are cookies passed in the HTTP protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467114/how-are-cookies-passed-in-the-http-protocol)

Comment: I try to read the header... But i can't find cookies on the header so i can't save them