# How to accept cookies from another domain

Tags: javascript, http, cookies, browser

If site A have cookies, Why if site B made a request to site A the browser don't send those cookies with the request?

I don't see any security here, Site B won't be able to read the cookies anyway. I just want to browser to send site A cookies when making requests to it.

How I could do that?

Answer (score 0):

Sites don't make requests, The bowers does. 
While making requests, you can set cookies as you wish.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467114/how-are-cookies-passed-in-the-http-protocol) thread

Comment: So why the browser don't send the cookies?. I can see that the site have a lot of cookies, but they are not sent with a request from another domain.