# Are the cookies not passed in the request header (in R)?

Tags: r, cookies, get

**Edit:**

Example from the documentation:

```
r <- GET("http://httpbin.org/cookies", set_cookies(a = 1, b = 2))
```

I would expect that the Cookies to be i the request headers:

```
r$request$headers
                                            Accept 
"application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*"
```

**Long Version:**

I do a get request in R:

```
library(httr)
library(magrittr)
url <- "https://www.r-bloggers.com"
r <- url %>% GET
```

And collect the cookies being used:

```
ck <- cookies(r)$value
names(ck) <- cookies(r)$name
```

Next i set the cookies:

```
#url <- "https://www.r-bloggers.com" same page or
url <- "https://www.r-bloggers.com/econometrics-postdoc-and-computational-statistics-postdoc-openings-here-in-the-stan-group-at-columbia/"
req <- url %>% GET(set_cookies(.cookies = ck))
```

and then i would expect that i sent the cookies with the headers.

```
req$request$headers
```

I would expect the cookies being in the request header, because of this: [How are cookies passed in the HTTP protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467114/how-are-cookies-passed-in-the-http-protocol).
And i assume these are my request headers `req$request$headers`.

Answer (score 0):

An answer was posted on Github: https://github.com/r-lib/httr/issues/629#issuecomment-557802675.

Cookies are sent, just not seen in the `request$headers` variable:

```
r <- GET("https://httpbin.org/cookies", set_cookies(a = 1, b = 2))
content(r)
```

**Edit:**

Answer from jennybc on GitHub:

```
with_verbose(GET(url = "https://www.r-bloggers.com", set_cookies(.cookies = c(a = "1"))))
```